# How to join Hbase table from another Hbase table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

everyone

I am new to Hadoop World and i have some problem with Hbase join.

I have two cluster,clusterA's Hbase have employee table ,clusterB's Hbase have department table.

So,how to join empolyee and department ?

Should i need to install Hive ?

Comment: You can try phoenix that supports Join. Take a look at this https://phoenix.apache.org/joins.html

Comment: Thanks Bro. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are in two separate clusters, you'll need to get one of the *HBase* tables from one cluster to another. This can be done via [*sqoop*](http://sqoop.apache.org/).

From there, you could, in theory, use *Phoenix* as suggested by *Vignesh I* in the comments, however, there are some limitations there. You would need to create a *Phoenix* view of both of those *HBase* tables. Native *HBase* views in *Phoenix*, currently, do not automatically update if they are updated outside of *Phoenix*, which most native *HBase* tables would be. This effectively renders views of native *HBase* tables in *Phoenix* snapshots instead of views; you will need to rebuild any indexes on a regular basis (and potentially stats as well) in order to capture any updates to the underlying *HBase* tables.

There is a JIRA open to enhance this behavior so that it would auto update, but the ETA of such a feature is unknown at this time.

What I would recommend, unless you have very specific real-time needs (in which case *Phoenix*, if you could live with the view limitations, may be the better choice), is to use [*Pig*](https://pig.apache.org/).

Within the *Pig* script, you can join the two *HBase* tables and then perform various transformations.

*Hive* would be another option, but in that case, you would need to *sqoop* both tables from *HBase* into *Hive*, and then proceed from there within *Hive*.